# Excel MATCH returns N/A all the time

Tags: excel, match

I know this question is everywhere but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I have table that I cannot change the sort order on.  The real data is a much larger table.

What's in the screens shot is just sample data because I thought maybe it was something in the real worksheet that was preventing it from working.  Also, in the real sheet, the data in columns A through C are drop down values so there's no chance of a typo there.  I have updated the drop downs to just Text and Number cells in this example.

The only thing I can think of is it's something sort related.  But again, I cannot sort the table.  VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, I can't get those to work either and I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct.

Please, help me understand what I'm doing wrong.  I'm pretty frustrated and **thanks to everyone in advance**.

I've verified cell formatting:

Columns A and D are Number and Columns B and C are Text

[image]I've tried the following:

=MATCH("Spice,cumin,powder",A31:D35,1)

=MATCH(A38,A31:D35,0)

=MATCH(C31,A31:D35,0)

=MATCH(A38,$A$31:$D$35,0)

=MATCH(TRIM(A38),A31:D35,0)

=MATCH(CLEAN(A38),A31:D35,0)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a The first argument is the match criteria, the second is the column range. What do you expect as result?

Comment: If you want a matching value from another column you may want to use XLOOKUP

Comment: Does this =MATCH(A38,C31:C35,0) works? For testing you can also =MATCH(C31,C31:C35,0)

Comment: Match only returns the Position of the match in the array (I.e. 1, 2, 5). Is this what you want? If you want the actual cell text (or, say the text from the same row but different column) you need to preceed the MATCH with INDEX. something like =INDEX(D31:D35,MATCH(A38,C31:C35,0))        (INDEX MATCH was the "more flexible" version of VLookup before XLookup came along.)

Comment: Btw, a sorted reference column is only relevant if you do NOT want EXACT match but allow approximate match.

Comment: I am expecting not "#N/A".  It seems that no matter what I enter for my criteria the value in B28 is always, "#N/A".  

Anon -- "Does this =MATCH(A38,C31:C35,0) works? For testing you can also =MATCH(C31,C31:C35,0)" 
----- this works.  I didn't think to try just one column.  So the difference is, yours only highlight a single column not a range of columns like I had.  Is single column a prerequisite for MATCH to work?

Thanks Stax.  I don't have XLookup.  I will need INDEX and MATCH to get particular values - thank you.

Anon, yea, I need an exact match.  

Thank you!